# Python Uvicorn FastAPI Docker-Compose Error Torchaudio?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, fastapi, uvicorn

I'm relatively new with Python (about a year experience) but have very limited experience in Docker. I'm currently making a FastAPI service which runs different AI models / integrations with other applications i have.

I'm currently running FastAPI with Uvicorn on an Ubuntu 20.04 VM. (see screenshot for file structure) Whenever i run FastAPI using "python3 -m uvicorn app.main:app --reload" in the terminal the service starts and works as expected. [image: File structure]

Whenever i try build a docker image and run it using "docker-compose up" it starts building but ends up with spitting out errors/warnings does someone know what i did wrong?

[image: Docker output]

I've added my Dockerfile and Docker-compose.yml files, hope that helps. I've spend 4 days trial-and-error but i have no idea what does wrong. (Probably something really simple...)

DockerFile:

```
FROM python:3.8.10

WORKDIR /code
COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
COPY ./app /code/app
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
CMD python3 -m uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
```

Docker-Compose:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  app:
    build: .
      command: python3 -m uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

Requirements.txt:

```
fastapi
uvicorn
pandas
numpy
wget
ffmpeg-python
transformers
torch
whisper
gitpython
mutagen
pydantic
mysql-connector-python
starlette
attribute
deep_translator
pyannote.audio
pydub
sox
```

Comment: Please make sure to include backtraces and similar terminal output as plain text and not images.  The specific error message `sndfile library not found` will find you the linked question; you need to `RUN apt-get install libsndfile1-dev` in your Dockerfile to install the corresponding C library.

Comment: @David Maze Thanks! Adding:
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get --yes install libsndfile1-dev
to my dockerfile it seems to work!